# The similar topic about how to get back my ETH stuck in a contract address

Tags: etherscan, recovery

I attended a group titled of Binance BSC smart contract project.

We can send three times ETH to a smart contract address, and to get BNB back, every time 10-15% of ETH value.

And the first and second time, we should send at least 0.3ETH. The third time we should send 0.45ETH.

I got BNB back at the first two times. But didn't get the return of the third time. It's still stuck in the contract address.

I questioned customer service, said, I should market BNB OVER in Transaction Data as remark so can get it back. Then I asked how to solve it, they said I should remit another 0.45ETH marked with BNB RECOVER. So it can be activated.

I thought it is just a lie.

And I really want this money back to my TRUST WALLET.

Below is the information.:

TRUST WALLET address: `0xD93b49D288858376428665F4C947dA5771d40251`

Smart contract address: `0x0Fe161eB79c73BA6B7C5347362C0e8aB29c7cDbA`

Block namea: `14485528`

You can check all in ETHERSCAN website: https://etherscan.io/address/0xD93b49D288858376428665F4C947dA5771d40251

Comment: it is a scam..... you cant ask scammer to refund you u because they are scammer...

Comment: somebody said it can be, somebody said it can't be...